# cat command not found even tough package is installed

Tags: command-line, vmware, cat

I've been running Ubuntu 20.04.3 in a VM for a few weeks without any major problems but when i tried to use cat today it only said:

```
Command 'cat' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install coreutils
```

I have coreutils installed and the other commands like tree and touch work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The question is not "What am I doing wrong?" but "What did you do before, to get to lose your cat? Did you leave the door open? Just kidding. More seriously, did you try to delete something and delete cat along with it?

Comment: I don't think i  did but while looking through some old snapshots i found out that whereis cat used to print `cat: /usr/bin/cat /usr/share/man/man1/cat.1.gz`
 but now it  only prints `cat: /usr/share/man/man1/cat.1.gz.` I think that might be the problem but i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: can you reinstall using `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`

Comment: Just did and it works again now, thank you :)

Comment: @pLumo Consider converting the comment to an answer. Teddy, if pLumo converts the comment to an answer. Please accept the answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say what happened, maybe you removed the binary by accident.

You can reinstall the package using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```